# Flutter Charts with Y axis displaying minutes:seconds:cents

Tags: flutter, charts, duration

I'm developing an app with Flutter that must display timing competition results of swim races. I'm not able to represent on the Y axis min:sec:mills. It seems the only value Charts accepts is int. Is there any way to fix?

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot or some piece of code that describes the problem in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this function below which converts `String` in the format min:sec:mils to milliseconds of type `int`. Use this to represent Y axis in your chart. In labels of Y axis use the `String` in min:sec:mils format itself.

**Note 1:** You need to pass the `String` value of format `min:sec:mils` into the function. **Example:** `"24:36:10"`.

**Note 2:** Function returns an `int` value.

```
int convertToMilliseconds(String time) {
  var arr = time.split(':');
  String min = arr[0];
  String sec = arr[1];
  String mils = arr[2];
  int a = int.parse(min);
  int b = int.parse(sec);
  int c = int.parse(mils);
  int intTimeInMilliseconds = Duration(minutes: a).inMilliseconds + Duration(seconds: b).inMilliseconds + c ;
return intTimeInMilliseconds;
}
```

**Full Example:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
       primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
       visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  /*This is a 800 meters running race data
  * David RUDISHA = 1:40:91
  * Wilson KIPKETER = 1:41:11
  * Sebastian COE = 1:41:73
  * Nijel AMOS = 1:41:73
  * Joaquim CRUZ = 1:41:77 */

  static const String Racer1Name = 'David RUDISHA';
  static const String Racer2Name = 'Wilson KIPKETER';
  static const String Racer3Name = 'Sebastian COE';
  static const String Racer4Name = 'Nijel AMOS';
  static const String Racer5Name = 'Joaquim CRUZ';

  static const String Racer1Time = '1:40:91';
  static const String Racer2Time = '1:41:11';
  static const String Racer3Time = '1:41:73';
  static const String Racer4Time = '1:41:73';
  static const String Racer5Time = '1:41:77';

  int Racer1TimeMilliSeconds = convertToMilliseconds(Racer1Time);
  int Racer2TimeMilliSeconds = convertToMilliseconds(Racer2Time);
  int Racer3TimeMilliSeconds = convertToMilliseconds(Racer3Time);
  int Racer4TimeMilliSeconds = convertToMilliseconds(Racer4Time);
  int Racer5TimeMilliSeconds = convertToMilliseconds(Racer5Time);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String Racer1TimeStringMilliSeconds = Racer1TimeMilliSeconds.toString();
    String Racer2TimeStringMilliSeconds = Racer2TimeMilliSeconds.toString();
    String Racer3TimeStringMilliSeconds = Racer3TimeMilliSeconds.toString();
    String Racer4TimeStringMilliSeconds = Racer4TimeMilliSeconds.toString();
    String Racer5TimeStringMilliSeconds = Racer5TimeMilliSeconds.toString();

    final List<RaceData> chartData = [
      RaceData(
          Racer1TimeMilliSeconds,
          '${Racer1Name}' +
              '\nminutes:seconds:milliseconds ${Racer1Time}' +
              '\n${Racer1TimeStringMilliSeconds} milliseconds'),
      RaceData(
          Racer2TimeMilliSeconds,
          '${Racer2Name}' +
              '\nminutes:seconds:milliseconds ${Racer2Time}' +
              '\n${Racer2TimeStringMilliSeconds} milliseconds'),
      RaceData(
          Racer3TimeMilliSeconds,
          '${Racer3Name}' +
              '\nminutes:seconds:milliseconds ${Racer3Time}' +
              '\n${Racer3TimeStringMilliSeconds} milliseconds'),
      RaceData(
          Racer4TimeMilliSeconds,
          '${Racer4Name}' +
              '\nminutes:seconds:milliseconds ${Racer4Time}' +
              '\n${Racer4TimeStringMilliSeconds} milliseconds'),
      RaceData(
          Racer5TimeMilliSeconds,
          '${Racer5Name}' +
              '\nminutes:seconds:milliseconds ${Racer5Time}' +
              '\n${Racer5TimeStringMilliSeconds} milliseconds'),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: SfCartesianChart(
            primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
              // Axis labels will be rotated to 90 degree
                labelRotation: 0,
                labelIntersectAction: AxisLabelIntersectAction.multipleRows,
            ),
          title: ChartTitle(
              text: 'Race Data',
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              borderColor: Colors.black,
              borderWidth: 1,
              // Aligns the chart title to left
              alignment: ChartAlignment.center,
              textStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                fontSize: 20,
              )),

          series: <ChartSeries>[
            // Renders line chart

            ColumnSeries<RaceData, String>(
              dataSource: chartData,
              xValueMapper: (RaceData race, _) => race.name,
              yValueMapper: (RaceData race, _) => race.time,
              enableTooltip: true,

              dataLabelSettings: DataLabelSettings(
                // Renders the data label
                isVisible: true,
                angle: 0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RaceData {
  RaceData(this.time, this.name);

  final String name;
  final int time;
}

int convertToMilliseconds(String time) {
  var arr = time.split(':');
  print(arr);
  String min = arr[0];
  String sec = arr[1];
  String mils = arr[2];
  int a = int.parse(min);
  int b = int.parse(sec);
  int c = int.parse(mils);
  int intTimeInMilliseconds = Duration(minutes: a).inMilliseconds +
      Duration(seconds: b).inMilliseconds +
      c;
  return intTimeInMilliseconds;
}
```

**Tablet View:**

[image: Valid XHTML]

**Mobile View:**

[image: Valid XHTML]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in flutter the Y axis accepts only number. This is the message I get: The return type 'String' isn't a 'num', as required by the closure's context.

Comment: Yes before passing the ```String``` it need to be converted to ```int```. The above function converts the ```String``` to ```int```. Before passing it to Y axis component of your program you need to call this function and pass the ```String```. You will get an ```int``` value in return. That value has to be passes to Y axis component of your code.

Comment: I'm using flutter and syncfusion charts and with the SfCartesianChart there is no way to use String Labels on Y axis. I'm able to plot a graph but in Y axis I see milliseconds and this is not acceptable. I have to display something like min:sec:millisec.

Comment: Please Check.. I have made editing to the answer. It all depends how to present the data to the user. Everything is understandable to the use in the above graph. Also look at the code. If you like it please select the and vote for the answer. I will get some reputation points for it...

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciated but I need timing in min:sec:mill on the Y axis or at least on the label on top of the bar. Anyway you've been so kind in replaying that I select your reply. By the way if you understand how to change the Y axis please add another comment.